# how to change style text after checked a checkbox

Tags: html, css, styles, checked

I would like to change the style of the text inside the

`<input type="checkbox" /> Origano`

to make "Origano" with style `text-decoration:line-through` after an user checked the box

Answer (score 1):

One way in recent browsers;

```
.selection_checkbox:checked + .selection_label {
 text-decoration:line-through;
}

<input id="oregano" type="checkbox" class="selection_checkbox" /> 
<label for="oregano" class="selection_label">Oregano</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/NR2Rr/

Comment: It's ok! Tnk you very mutch

Answer (score -1):

You can add this to your css file

```
input[type="checkbox"][checked]{text-decoration:line-through}
```